# Can't access properties of object

Tags: javascript, object

I have this three console.log calls for testing in my code:

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data.url);
console.log(data["url"]);
```

The output in the console is:

```
mySC.js:85 Object {}songArtist: "Kasbo" songTitle: "Kasbo - Found You (Feat. Chelsea Cutler) " thumbnail: "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000216213225-csqjf0-t500x500.jpg" url: "https://soundcloud.com/kasbomusic/found-you-feat-chelsea-cutler"__proto__: Object
mySC.js:86 undefined
mySC.js:87 undefined
```

Where is my error? Why I don't get the url of this object?

#### EDIT

These are the function calls where I pass the data

```
playSC(iFrame, song, false, function(data) {
  updateSongInfo(data);
});

function updateSongInfo(data) {
  updateLink(data.url);

  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.url);
  console.log(data["url"]);
}

function playSC(player, song, autoPlay, callback) {
  player.load(song, {
    auto_play: autoPlay,
    callback: function () {
      var data = getSCinfo(song);
      if(callback) {
        callback(data);
      }
    }
  });
}

function getSCinfo(song){
  var scUrl = 'https://soundcloud.com/oembed.json?maxheight=200&url='+song;
  var computedData = {};

  getAjax(scUrl, function(data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var thumbHttps = jsonData.thumbnail_url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
    var titleOnly = jsonData.title.split("by");

    computedData.thumbnail = thumbHttps;
    computedData.songTitle = titleOnly[0];
    computedData.songArtist = jsonData.author_name;
    computedData.url = song;
  });

  return computedData;
}
```

Comment: Post the mentioned object.

Comment: Do you mean where it gets created?

Comment: I mean not the output in the console but the real object.

Comment: Yes, he means where the object gets defined / set.

Comment: You could try logging `data [0].url`

Comment: That object trace looks wonky. Do a "for ( let each of data ) { console.log ( each ); console.log ( data [ each ] ); }". What do you get?

Comment: @TimConsolazio for..of loops aren't supported by my JS version and a for loop with `(var i; i <= data.length...)` isn't possible because of `data.length` is undefined.

Comment: try for (var prop in obj)

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: And for the output: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)